# Hoy to make car returns in javascript exporting to CSV?

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, quotes

I have to export some data to CSV with javascript. I need to show some columns as a list in one cell, not as a simple string.
I tried adding \n, \r or \r\n at the end of each item but they were printed in the next row; instead of in the same cell. 
Then I tried adding quotes at the start and end of the list. Like this:

```
"item1
item2
item3"
```

This seemed to work but if one of the items has quotes:

```
"ite"m1
item2
item3"
```

It isn't showed correctly, as well as it show the next item in other row.
Do you know another way to show the list, instead of adding quotes at the start and end of the list? Thanks

Comment: Please do share you code!

Comment: When word comes CSV it should be CSV(comma separated value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, quotes are the only way to escape newline characters, so you will have to stick with this method for now.

## Solution

Use quotes.

If one of the items has quotes in its content, you have to **double** them, like so :

```
"ite""m1
item2
item3"
```

In Excel, this will output, as a **single** value, to :

```
ite"m1
item2
item3
```

Comment: What are you trying to explain here?

Comment: @UllasHunka sorry if I wasn't clear, I'll try to clarify by editing

Comment: This worked! It's so simple that I never would have thought about it. Thanks you very much for your answer.